# C# LINQ join 3 tables with outer join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggeling to join 3 tables with outer join.
Below is my code:

```
                var nodedbs = (from dnb in fp.DataNodeBase
                              join res in fp.Results on dnb.DataNodeBase_Id equals res.DataNodeBase_Id into dnbres
                              from res in dnbres.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join queryres in fp.DataNodeQueryResult on res.Results_Id equals queryres.Results_Id into nodeandquery
                              from queryres in nodeandquery.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where (dnb.Nodes_Id == operatorstation.OperatorStation_Id)
                              && ((dnb.IsNull("Family") ? "" : dnb.Family).Contains("File Compare") == false)
                               select new {
                                  NodeID = dnb.Nodes_Id,
                                  ResultsDataNodeBaseID = (res == null ? -1 : res.DataNodeBase_Id),
                                  NodeDataBaseNodeID = dnb.DataNodeBase_Id,
                                  DataNodeQueryResults = (queryres == null ? -1 : queryres.Results_Id)
                              }).ToArray();
```

With this i'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I assume it is because i'm joining on a field "res.Results_Id" that potentially is null?
Is there a way around this?

Comment: Only you can see where the null object is. We can't. Also, what is `fp`? In other words: is this LINQ to a SQL backend? If so, which type of LINQ?

Comment: It's LINQ to a de-serialized custom class, fp is the custom class

Answer (score 0):

To debug this i recommend to separate this to a few sub queries.
But in your case the problem is the `DefaultIfEmpty` function, it might return 
a collection with one "default" element for reference type the default is `null`
So you need to check if `dnbres.Any()` and ALWAYS check for null before using `.` on something.
You can use `?.` [for null check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and provide default value in the end.
 like this :

`if (obj?.IsValid ?? false)
 {
     // not valid or obj is null
 }`

So your code will look something like :

```
  if ((fp?.DataNodeBase?.IsAny() ?? false) &&
      (fp?.Results?.IsAny() ?? false))
  {
       var nodedbs =
           (from dnb in fp.DataNodeBase
                 join res in fp.Results on dnb.DataNodeBase_Id equals 
                 res.DataNodeBase_Id into dnbres
                 from res in dnbres
                 join queryres in fp.DataNodeQueryResult on res.Results_Id equals 
                      queryres.Results_Id into nodeandquery
                 from queryres in nodeandquery
                 where( dnb.Nodes_Id == operatorstation.OperatorStation_Id) && 
                        ((dnb.IsNull("Family") ? "" : dnb.Family).Contains("FileCompare") == false)
                 select new
                 {
                     NodeID = dnb.Nodes_Id,
                     ResultsDataNodeBaseID = (res == null ? -1 : res.DataNodeBase_Id),
                     NodeDataBaseNodeID = dnb.DataNodeBase_Id,
                     DataNodeQueryResults = (queryres == null ? -1 : queryres.Results_Id)
                 }).ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have came accross this problem couple of times in my project, update your code like this to overcome the error. part of your code as follows

```
 select new
      {
        NodeID = ((dnb != null)? dnb.Nodes_Id : 0),
        ResultsDataNodeBaseID = ((res != null) ? res.DataNodeBase_Id : -1),
        NodeDataBaseNodeID = ((dnb != null)? dnb.DataNodeBase_Id : 0),
        DataNodeQueryResults = ((queryres != null) ? queryres.Results_Id : -1)
      }).ToArray();
```

Note: Check object is not null before accessing the data member of the object